# on page refresh POST array do not get empty

Tags: php

I created a form in php with action as the same page url and method as POST

```
    <?php
            if(isset($_POST['submitted']) && $_POST['submitted'] != ''){
                    echo $_POST['fname'];
                    echo "<br />";
                    echo $_POST['lname'];
                    echo "<br />";
                    echo $_POST['submitted'];
            }
    ?>
    <h1>testing...</h1>

    <form action="test.php" method="POST">
            First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" />
            Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" />
            <input type="submit" name="submitted" />
    </form>
```

When I enter data and submit it, page shows the data as I printed the data. But when I refresh page the data still exists, I want the data to be shown only when I click submit.

Can anybody help me in this?
Am I doing something wrong.

Comment: If you refresh the page after the submit, your browser will ask you if you want re-transmit your data again.

Comment: The data still shows because you are resubmitting it when you refresh.  What behaviour do you want to occur?

Comment: Please give a `value="something"` attribute to your submit button...

Comment: Vote to close: The OP hasn't given an example of what the expected behaviour should be.

Comment: Expected behaviour for browser is  "I want the data to be shown only when I click submit"

Comment: You can use then GET method instead of POST or can pass header() to the same page but in this case you need to store data either in db or in $_SESSION otherwise it will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK. This is a standard browser behavior to repeat last request with f5 button.

My understanding for what do you need to prevent it. It's to prevent 'spam'.

So, you need to understand that first submit was already made.

As test idea you can add timestamp for send button and check it on send. In this case timestamp from button and on send will be different for refreshing

Comment: I got the issue, now trying to fix it. This link explains it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that

0) {
        $_SESSION['shout'] = $_POST['shout'];

        header("HTTP/1.1 303 See Other");
        header("Location: http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/echochamber.php");
        die();
    }
    else if (isset($_SESSION['shout'])){
        $echoedShout = $_SESSION['shout'];

        /*
            Put database-affecting code here.
        */

        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
    }
?>

OR I did that in codeigniter using set_flashdata which stores session data for next request only.